# What does it mean that the curvature is zero in a single point?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, plane-curves

Consider a unit-speed curve $c:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\kappa:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be the curvature. Assume there is a point $t_0 \in I$ with $\kappa(t_0)=0$. Does this mean that $c$ is a straight line locally around $t_0$? That is, there is some $\varepsilon >0$ and two elements $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$c(t)=a+bt\phantom{aaa}\forall t \in (t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon).$$
I am asking this because I try to understand the relationship between curvature, second derivatives and osculating circles in a geometrically accessible way. Intuitively, I guess the answer should be yes because otherwise, we can construct the osculating circle at $c(t_0)$. But if $r$ is the radius, we would have $r=1/\kappa(t_0)$ which is impossible for $\kappa(t_0)=0$. If that is true, is there an easy way to make this argument more formal?

Comment: The analogus question for function is: if $f''(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0$, does it mean that $f$ is locally a straight line?

Comment: @ArcticChar, I guess not. But if it is not a straight line, why can't we construct the osculating circle then?

Comment: Here's a sketch: If $\kappa(t_{0}) = 0$ then up to a translation and rotation (namely, Taylor-expanding the curve the curve with respect to its tangent and normal at $t_{0}$), the curve has equation $y = ax^{k}(1 + o(x))$, in some neighborhood of $x = 0$, for some real $a$ and some integer $k \geq 3$. The only curve of degree $1$ or $2$ meeting this curve at the origin to order greater than $2$ is the $x$-axis $y = 0$.

Comment: The standard definition is inflexion point : see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point. The tangent is osculating, namely is tangent at the order 3, not 2, and the center of the osculating circle goes to infinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you throw a ball into the air, the $y$ velocity becomes zero at one moment of time.  That does not mean that the $y$ velocity remains $0$ over any interval; that would mean that there was no acceleration, which would correspond to gravity being turned off for a short while.

For the curve $y = \sin x$, the curvature is zero at every multiple of $\pi$.  Those are the points where the curve switches from concave up to concave down or vice versa.  That does not mean that the sine curve becomes a straight line over an interval.